Is it wrong to say that energy *is* motion?
I am curious, to what extent can we think about energy as motion? Oftentimes, when the question is raised, ‘what is energy?’, the response is that it is some abstract invariant that is not directly measurable in the laboratory, but yields experimentally verifiable observable quantities (such as velocity).
Is it wrong to say that energy is motion? The following is my argument. All forces of nature impart an acceleration on objects with which they interact. Conservative forces, by definition, have potential functions, say, $U$, such that $\vec{F}=-\nabla U$. The work energy theorem shows that the change in this quantity over some path (work) is equal to the corresponding change in kinetic energy (over that path). Solving for $\vec{v}$, can we say that velocity is a function of potential energy? In other words, Energy is motion?
If potential energy is zero, there is no motion. If not, there is motion governed by the above equations and the relevant equations of motion.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The problem is that the term energy is such a broad term, and covers such a large range of systems, that trying to come up with an intuitive definition for it like energy is motion will inevitably fail.
For example consider a stationary hydrogen atom with the electron in the $2s$ orbital. Nothing is moving here, and there is not even any (orbital) angular momentum, and yet this has energy that can be released when it transitions to the ground state. So how would you reconcile this with the energy is motion idea?
The reason we fall back to the rather arcane definition that energy is the conserved quantity associated with time shift symmetry is because it works. By all means look for more intuitive notions, but bear in mind that they will always be limited.

Thanks for the nice answer! I actually am not sure what it means to talk about electronic motion in an atom. There is a probability amplitude associated to finding the electron is some position in space, so you may come up with some argument about motion in quantum mechanical terms?

@Spinor The probability of finding the electron does not change with time. If the electron were moving around inside the atom the probability would be changing with time, but it isn't. Ergo the electron in the atom is not moving.

It is possible to construct states of the hydrogen atom where the electron is moving, but these are mixtures of states like a mixture of the 1s and 2p states. See Is there oscillating charge in a hydrogen atom? for more on this.

I understand that time-independent wavefunctions are typically described as ‘stationary’, but my point is that there is no telling what the electron is doing, other than the statements you and I have made: we can compute a wavefunction with a time-independent spatial distribution. Classically, if I put a ball in a box and don’t touch it, its spatial distribution is a delta function. Don’t you agree that is quite different than the ’stationary’ in QM described above?

Yes, it is quite different. The electron in a hydrogen atom is not a little ball bouncing round, it is the wavefunction i.e. it is like a fuzzy cloud not a little ball. This is something newcomers to QM find hard to grasp. Quantum particles are always delocalised to some extent.

Our universe is NOT classical. It obeys quantum theory. If you insist upon using classical viewpoint, then you cannot hope to understand what Nature is doing.

Moreover, standing waves do not disqualify ‘motion’ even in classical settings. Standing waves on guitar strings also have time-independent amplitude distribtions, but that’s because of interference. Given that electrons are waves, I’m tempted to think along these lines.

@Spinor then you'd be wrong. The oscillating phase of e.g. the hydrogen 1s state is not like a guitar string. It is more like the rotation of circularly polarised light. You can think of the wavefunction at a point as a phasor with a constant amplitude. Since the electron density is the magnitude squared, the electron density is always constant and does not oscillate.

@naturallyInconsistent that was exactly my point.. although, to play devil’s advocate, semi-classical thinking is oftentimes very useful, especially in the lab.

By the way, @JohnRennie, I must say it’s clear why your reputation is high! Despite the playfulness and unorthodox nature of this question, you remain open and grounded, and that is much appreciated. However meaningful it is to you, I am impressed by your depth and level of argument. My background and day-to-day as a practicing physicist obviously is far removed from my behavior here. Was having some fun with the Feynman lectures and thought I’d have a fun discussion here. Thanks to you (not so much others that are negatively audacious, unwelcoming, and overly presumptuous)!

Kinetic energy is a function of motion.
The transfer of energy will always involve motion of some sort.
Both those statements are more true and descriptive than saying "energy is motion".
It's sort of like saying "time is money" - there's a big connection between the two, but it's not precisely correct in the way you'd need it to be to consider it a philosophical or physical truth.

The transfer of energy will always involve motion of some sort. In classical electromagnetism, the transport of energy in an electromagnetic field does not involve motion, unless you want to call changes in field values “motion” or the movement of field energy “motion”. In classical physics, “motion” should mean the movement of particles, and no particles are moving in a classical EM wave.

The thermodynamics of magnetic materials, spin flips jumping around and carrying heat that way, is not motion of the usual kind.

@Ghoster photons are moving. Also for an EM wave to exist there need to be source currents of some sort.

I said classical electromagnetism, in which photons don’t exist. And Maxwell’s equations allow waves without source currents.

@Ghoster classical electromagnetism is an approximate model where you don't have to worry about individual photons, that doesn't mean photons don't exist? Should be obvious. And no, maxwell's equations do not allow waves without moving charges at the source.

Yes, they do. “Maxwell's equations support a ‘sourceless’ electromagnetic wave, as if it has existed forever.” You should have no problem verifying this mathematically.

At the time that Maxwell finalized classical electromagnetism, it was not an approximation to QED. It was, and is, a consistent theory in its own right, which has no photons but nevertheless transports energy in electromagnetic waves without anything worthy of being called “motion”.

Similarly, in General Relativity, gravitational waves transport energy without motion. There are no gravitons in GR, and no evidence yet that the gravitons predicted by speculative theories of quantum gravity exist.

Finally, the word “motion” is a classical concept implying a definite position and velocity at each instant, which quanta don’t have.

I was hoping that you would improve your answer, so I hadn’t downvoted. But you haven’t, so now I did. This discussion has been lengthy enough that I’m not going to comment further.
